# Envelope budgeting software that won't break the bank

Tags: web-apps, finance

I'm looking for a budgeting software with specific features. I tried out YNAB and it's perfect but too expensive.

**Here's what I need:**

- Create budgets for multiple categories
- Overview of how much money is left per budget (like YNAB - see screenshot below)
- Manual transaction creation
- Free or low-priced subscription
- Web or desktop app (preferably web though)

**Here's what I don't need:**

- Linked bank accounts
- Multiple wallets
- Phone app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

YNAB might be too pricey. I am in the same situations of you. But I have a suggestion.

YNAB is more than a software. It's a kind of habit-making software. So just subscribe it for 1 year or 2 years.

Once you are on track, you can use some one-time paid software like Wallet by BudgetBakers.